# Remove Home page slug in translated pages

Tags: homepage, translation, home-url

I'm building a website in wordpress, and i've decided to use a custom page "home" for my website's home.
I know that i could use the `index.php` file for the home page , but i needed to use some plugins.

Moving forward i was doing the page translations to use for example : 
i created home , home-en , home-fr and so on... and when i set the `home` as the home page it removed it's slug, but not on the translated pages...

They still appear like this

[image]

Is there any way to remove this and just let it be `/en` ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what plugin are you using for translations?

Comment: I'm currently using Polylang!